# tcl/tk scrollbar not working

Tags: scrollbar, tcl, tk-toolkit

i am given a frame and i try to put a scrollable canvas into it.
everything seems to work fine and i get scrollbar but they dont seem to work.
scrollbar does expand and contract when i resize window and does move when i click on its bottom or top.

for frame .f and canvas .f.c
my yview output changes when i try to scroll

i.e

```
.f.c yview
.08 .35
.f.c yview
.38 .62
.f.c yview
.75 1
```

i am not sure what have i missed here?

```
frame .f
canvas .f.c
```

put few labels
place them

```
scrollbar .f.ysb -orient vertical -command ".f.c yview"

.f.c configure -yscrollcommand ".f.ysb set" -scrollregion [list -1000 -1000 1000 1000]

grid .f.c -row 0 -column 0 -sticky nsew
grid .f.ysb -row 0 -column 1 -sticky ns

grid columnconfigure .f 0 -weight 1

grid rowconfigure .f 0 -weight 1
```